# How to access a private variables using a common public function within the constructor

Tags: javascript, variables, properties, constructor, private

How to access a private variables using a common public function within the constructor.

```
function construct(){

    var priValue1 = 0;
    var priValue2 = 0;
    var priValue3 = 0;    

    this.getvalue = function(_input){
        return this[_input];
    }

}

construct.prototype.init = function(){
    if(this.getvalue("priValue1")){
        console.log("Value 1")
    }
}

var nc = new construct();
nc.init();
```

Couldn't  get access for the private variable.

Comment: `return _input` instead of `return this[_input]`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sandenay/0ac78v7d/

Comment: @SandeepNayak I don't think that will work. That will just return the argument passed in. I think they want to access the variables they declared.

Comment: Define variables on `this`. Ex. `this.priValue1 = 0` Code `function construct() {

    this.priValue1 = 110;
    this.priValue2 = 120;
    this.priValue3 = 130;

    this.getvalue = function (_input) {
        console.log(_input);
        console.log(this[_input]);
        return this[_input];
    };

}

construct.prototype.init = function () {
    if (this.getvalue("priValue1")) {
        console.log("Value 1");
    }
};

var nc = new construct();
nc.init();`

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara: Agreed. Missed that part ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could store your private variables in an object, and access them by property name.

```js
function construct(){
    var priVars = {
        priValue1: 0,
        priValue2: 0,
        priValue3: 0
    };

    this.getvalue = function(_input){
        return priVars[_input];
    }

}

construct.prototype.init = function(){
    if(this.getvalue("priValue1")){
        console.log("Value 1")
    }
}

var nc = new construct();
nc.init();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a "private var" this is not stored on `this`, the variable is accesible as a scope variable. Using your own code I would write

```
this.getvalue = function(_input){
    return eval(_input);
}
```

to get the value dynamically

Comment: Eww... If `eval` is the answer, the question is wrong.

Comment: Maybe the question is wrong, because you don't have private variables on javascript ;) Using an object its pretty good too!